# Using custom method from library to get all pairs (key, value) from App.config in c#

Tags: c#, app-config

I'm trying to build my own library of most often used methods/code. The method on which I'm currently working suppose to read all pairs (value, key) from provided section by user from the config file and log them into the logger. When I converted code into method and move it to separate file I found a problem related to location of *App.config*.

So I have my *App.config*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="General" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler"/>
    <section name="Generalxxxxxxxxxxxxx" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler"/>
  </configSections>
  <General>
    <add key="ApplicationName" value="Configuration Example Project"/>
    <add key="Language" value="CSharp"/>
    <add key="SecretKey" value="012345"/>
  </General>
  <Generalxxxxxxxxxxxxx>
    <add key="ApplicationName" value="Configuration Example Project"/>
    <add key="Language" value="CSharp"/>
    <add key="SecretKey" value="012345"/>
  </Generalxxxxxxxxxxxxx>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

From which I could read all pairs (key, value) by simply using following code. In this case when everything was under one file I didn't have to provide the *App.config* location.

```
var general = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("General") as NameValueCollection;  
            if (applicationSettings.Count == 0)  
            {  
                Console.WriteLine("Application Settings are not defined");  
            }  
            else  
            {  
                foreach (var key in general.AllKeys)  
                {  
                    Console.WriteLine(key + " = " + applicationSettings[key]);  
                }  
            }
```

I found a way to pass a location but now I can't read *sectionLoad* as *NameValueCollection* because of conversion error so I can't use *AllKeys* method.

```
 public static Tuple<string, string> LogSaveConfig(string location, string sectionName)
        {

            //var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
            var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(location);

            var sectionLoad = config.GetSection(sectionName);

            return Tuple.Create("key", "value"); //just temporary
        }
```

Also I did some debugging on "sectionLoad" and only place where I could found the pairs(key,values) was rawXML:
[image]

My question is how can I get the pairs(key, value) when I'm calling config file through method which is part of separate library? My goal is to be able to type `MyLib.LoggerDefined.LogSaveConfig(location, section);`
which is going to log the pairs(key, value) into logger. Also if my approach is wrong please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could read the xml file directly which is xml format.  I used xml linq and created a dictionary

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication158
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            Dictionary<string, List<List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>>> dict = doc.Root.Elements()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Name.LocalName, y => y.Elements()
                    .Select(z => z.Attributes().Select(a => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(a.Name.LocalName, (string)a)).ToList()).ToList())
                    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

        }
    }
}
```